# (cr, uid, frozendict(context) TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Tags: python, typeerror

I'm trying to update a field using onchange method in odoo.

My .py code is

```
class hr_contract(osv.osv):
_name = 'hr.contract'
_description = 'Contract'


def _wage(self, cr, uid, ids,context=None):
        res = {}
        pay_slip = 0
        pay_slip1 = 0

        for obj in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
            s1 = ("""select schedule_pay from hr_contract where employee_id=%s""" % (obj.employee_id.id))
            cr.execute(s1)
            l1 = cr.fetchone()
            value10 = l1[0]
            if value10 == 'bi-weekly':
                s4 = (
                    """select salary from hr_contract where employee_id=%s """ % (
                        obj.employee_id.id))
                cr.execute(s4)
                l4 = cr.fetchone()
                salary = l4[0]
                # **************************************************************#
                ######### Week1  #############
                s5 = ("""select week1 from hr_contract where employee_id=%s """ % (
                    obj.employee_id.id))
                cr.execute(s5)
                l5 = cr.fetchone()
                week1 = l5[0]
                print "week1", week1
                if week1 != None:
                    if week1 > 48.00:
                        weeked1 = week1 - 48.00
                        total_amt = salary * (weeked1 * 1.5)
                        total_pay = 48.00 * salary
                        pay_slip = total_amt + total_pay
                        pay_slip1 += pay_slip
                        print "payslip..", pay_slip
                        cr.execute(""" update hr_contract set week1=%s where employee_id=%s""" % (
                            week1, obj.employee_id.id))
                    else:
                        pay_slip = week1 * salary
                        pay_slip1 += pay_slip
                        print "payslip..", pay_slip1
```

While I change the field and save it shows error as

```
File "/home/rck/Desktop/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 769, in __new__
    self.cr, self.uid, self.context = self.args = (cr, uid, frozendict(context))
TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

If I remove the **context** from the for loop it takes the previous value for the computation.

how can I solve this?

I call the function using the onchange in xml

```
<field name="week1" on_change="_wage(week1)"/>
```

The field is set as float in py

```
 'wage': fields.float('Per Hour Wages'),
 'week1': fields.float('Week 1'),
```

Comment: Can you isolate the problem before posting 200 lines of code ?

Comment: the error is at the for loop  **for obj in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):**

Comment: Then please remove anything else that's not relevant. You want to *clarify* the problem, not dilute it.

Comment: I edited my question

Comment: can you post the snippet where _wage is being called? It looks like you're passing a float to the context param. Keep in mind, "context = None" in the function declaration does not set that variable, it sets what that variable would be if you do not provide it

Comment: I have posted the snippet

Answer (score 0):

This is waht the `TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable"` means :-

`count=7` for say then `for i in count:` means `for i in 7:`, which won't work. The bit after the `in` should be of an iterable type, not a number. Try this:

```
for i in range(count):
```

as mentioned in the comment isolate your problem to get more clearer answer.

Comment: it looks like the OP is using osv.osv.browse, which returns an iterable of objects. I do not think it's an issue with the for loop directly, but with passing a bad value to context. Removing context=context avoids the error, and in osv.osv.browse the default value is context=None

Comment: I also tried it. When I remove the context=context it takes the previous value of the field week1 not the current value